# How to vectorize the following python code

Tags: numpy, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, pytorch

I'm trying to obtain a matrix, where each element is calculated as follows:

```
X = torch.ones(batch_size, dim)
X_ = torch.ones(batch_size, dim)
Y = torch.ones(batch_size, dim)
M = torch.zeros(batch_size, batch_size)
for i in range(batch_size):
    for j in range(batch_size):
        M[i, j] = ((X[i] - X_[i] * Y[j])**2).sum()
```

It's very slow to calculate `M` element-wise, is there any suggestion about how to use matrix multiplication to replace the for loops?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I made a mistake when I transferred my code here. Actually X is a batch of vectors, so it is of size (batch_size, dim). So applying sum() will give a scalar. So I guess we need another version of vectorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `sum()` over dim, you can "lift" your 2D problem to 3D and sum there:

```
M = ((X[:, None, :] - X_[:, None, :] * Y[None, ...])**2).sum(dim=2)
```

**How it works**:

`X[:, None, :]` and `X_[:, None, :]` are 3D of size `(batch_size, 1, dim)`, and `Y[None, ...]` is of size `(1, batch_size, dim)`.

When multiplying `X_[:, None, :] * Y[None, ...]` pytorch [broadcasts](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#module-numpy.doc.broadcasting) the dimensions of size 1 to the appropriate dimension to get a result of size `(batch_size, batch_size, dim)`.
Finally, you `sum()` only over the last dimension `(dim=2)` to get an output `M` of size `(batch_size, batch_size)`.

The trick here is done by taking advantage of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#module-numpy.doc.broadcasting).

Comment: Thanks! Because M[i,j] is a scalar value

Comment: Thanks for explaining the code, it perfectly solves my problem.