# Subtract the elements of every possible pair of a torch Tensor efficiently

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a huge torch Tensor and I'm looking for an efficient approach to subtract the elements of every pair of that Tensor.
Of course I could use two nested for but it wouldn't be efficient.

For example giving

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The output I want is

```
[1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily:

```py
>>> x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x[:, None] - x[None, :]
tensor([[ 0, -1, -2, -3],
        [ 1,  0, -1, -2],
        [ 2,  1,  0, -1],
        [ 3,  2,  1,  0]])
```

see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442187/1714410).